# Creating rectangle in Tkinter for seperate buttons

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to create rectangle shape like in photo but I couldn't make it. What should I do for creating rectangle to seperate buttons ?

You can see in photos that I attached.

[That's what I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75eFO.jpg)

[That's what I've done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZA4kB.jpg)

Comment: Read up on [The Tkinter LabelFrame Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/labelframe.htm)

Comment: You can create [`Frame`](https://web.archive.org/web/20190528185415id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/frame.html) widget and put them all inside of it.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

- You will have to use a `Frame` widget as that suits your requirements, It is a widget made to be used in cases like yours.
- You will need to pass `highlightbackground='The Color You Want(Should be string)'` and `highlightthickness=How thick u want it to be(Should be int)` to the `Frame`, to get what you want.

Like I've done in this **Example:**

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('170x130')

# Outside the Rectangle
lbl = tk.Label(root, text='Test:')
e = tk.Entry(root)

lbl.grid(row=0, column=0)
e.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2)

# The Rectangle
rectangle = tk.Frame(root, highlightthickness=2, highlightbackground='black')
rectangle.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3, ipadx=40, ipady=20)

# Inside the Rectangle
b1 = tk.Button(rectangle, text='1')
b2 = tk.Button(rectangle, text='2')
b3 = tk.Button(rectangle, text='3')

b1.grid(row=0, column=0)
b2.grid(row=0, column=1)
b3.grid(row=0, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Frame(root, bd=1, relief=tk.SOLID, bg="black", highlightthickness=0)
```

put the rects inside it, you can use place instead of pack. Also canvas is a nice alternative too.